# Firestore Error - firebase:emulator:start - Firestore Emulator has exited with code: 1

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm in an angular 11 app, Previously I had an outdated version of java, but even after updating it and restarting the pc I keep getting an error when trying to start the local firestore emulator.

I've already done:

- npm i firebase @angular/fire
- added the neccessary config/modifications in my angular app
- firebase init (for firestore, hosting &
  emulator)
- created a firestore db on the firebase google console
- updated to java sdk 16

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure it out.

**Node & npm version**

```
node - v15.12.0
npm - 7.6.3
```

**My java version**

```
java version "16" 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**firebase-debug.log** (the firestore-debug.log is always empty)

```
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.737Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.739Z] Command:       C:\PROGRA~1\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js --debug emulators:start
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.739Z] CLI Version:   9.8.0
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.739Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.739Z] Node Version:  v15.12.0
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.740Z] Time:          Sun Apr 04 2021 12:06:47 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.740Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.745Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.747Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[info] i  emulators: Starting emulators: firestore, hosting {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Starting emulators: firestore, hosting"}}
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.762Z] [hub] writing locator at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Temp\hub-my-coffee-app-2.json
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.776Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId"}}
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.777Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download"}}
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:47.777Z] Starting Firestore Emulator with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Dgoogle.cloud_firestore.debug_log_level=FINE","-Duser.language=en","-jar","C:\\Users\\Dev\\.cache\\firebase\\emulators\\cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.12.jar","--host","127.0.0.1","--port",8080,"--rules","D:\\_Repos ‍ \\my-coffee-app-pwa\\my-coffee-app-web\\firestore.rules"],"optionalArgs":["port","webchannel_port","host","rules","functions_emulator","seed_from_export"],"joinArgs":false} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Starting Firestore Emulator with command {\"binary\":\"java\",\"args\":[\"-Dgoogle.cloud_firestore.debug_log_level=FINE\",\"-Duser.language=en\",\"-jar\",\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Dev\\\\.cache\\\\firebase\\\\emulators\\\\cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.12.jar\",\"--host\",\"127.0.0.1\",\"--port\",8080,\"--rules\",\"D:\\\\_Repos ‍ \\\\my-coffee-app-pwa\\\\my-coffee-app-web\\\\firestore.rules\"],\"optionalArgs\":[\"port\",\"webchannel_port\",\"host\",\"rules\",\"functions_emulator\",\"seed_from_export\"],\"joinArgs\":false}"}}
[info] i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Firestore Emulator logging to \u001b[1mfirestore-debug.log\u001b[22m"}}
[warn] !  firestore: Fatal error occurred: 
   Firestore Emulator has exited with code: 1, 
   stopping all running emulators {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Fatal error occurred: \n   Firestore Emulator has exited with code: 1, \n   stopping all running emulators"}}
[info] i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Stopping Firestore Emulator"}}
[debug] [2021-04-04T09:06:52.112Z] Firestore Emulator: Unable to terminate process (PID=16940) {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Firestore Emulator: Unable to terminate process (PID=16940)"}}
[warn] !  firestore: Error stopping Firestore Emulator {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Error stopping Firestore Emulator"}}
[info] i  hub: Stopping emulator hub {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Stopping emulator hub"}}
```

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-coffee-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.5",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^11.2.5",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngx-formly/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngx-formly/schematics": "^5.10.15",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "firebase": "^8.3.2",
    "material-theme-creator": "^3.0.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1200",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.8.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this on my side. Used the Java/node/npm versions, tried both win and linux. But I found this [angularfire issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2796) seems to be the same issue